# Как упростить код функции?

Tags: python, django, инспекция-кода

Задача: вернуть список заказов с опциональной передачей аргументов `limit` (это максимум сколько записей вернуть), и `offset` (это сколько сместить с начала)

Вот мой код, он работает, но мне кажется можно записать попроще, но не приходит в голову, как?

Основная проблема в том, что их могут и не передать, или передать только один, поэтому приходится каждый случай портянками обрабатывать...

```
def get_queryset(self):
    limit = self.request.query_params.get('LIMIT')
    offset = self.request.query_params.get('OFFSET')
    limit = int(limit) if limit else None
    offset = int(offset) if offset else None
    if limit and offset:
        return Orders.objects.all()[offset:offset+limit]
    if limit:
        return Orders.objects.all()[:limit]
    if offset:
        return Orders.objects.all()[offset:]
    return Orders.objects.all()
```

Comment: Функцию придётся наоборот усложнить, потому что если вдруг `LIMIT` и `OFFSET` окажутся не числами (а какой-нибудь злобный хакер вроде меня обязательно попробует подставить не-числа), то `int()` вывалит ошибку

Comment: @andreymal действительно, спасибо! а так в целом - тут особо проще и не напишешь?

Comment: Ещё отсутствие верхнего предела на `limit` это обычно тоже плохая идея, потому что если вдруг в базе лежит миллионы Orders'ов, то сервер будет очень сильно мучаться, пытаясь вывести все эти миллионы при отсутствующем limit (а ещё кстати не забывайте, что тот же злобный хакер может подставить отрицательные числа)

Comment: @andreymal да уж, хотел попроще, а оказалось вот так) пойду усложнять, большое спасибо))

Comment: Если поставить ограничения в примерно таком виде `limit = min(max(0, limit), 100)` и `offset = max(0, offset)` то от всех этих трёх if'ов можно будет избавиться и написать просто `return Orders.objects.all()[offset:offset+limit]` потому что значения offset и limit будут гарантированно корректные

Comment: @andreymal а вот это очень хорошо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Для наглядности

```py
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
offset = 3
limit = 2

data[(offset or 0):(offset or 0)+(limit or 0)]
# [4, 5]
```

#### В вашем случае

```py
def get_queryset(self):
# Можно так если отсутствие лимита означает максимальный лимит
# (При наличии большого набора данных может быть тяжко)
#    limit = int(self.request.query_params.get('LIMIT', len(Orders.objects.all())))
# Или так. Если считать отсутствие лимита как то, что его забыли указать
    limit = int(self.request.query_params.get('LIMIT', 0))
    offset = int(self.request.query_params.get('OFFSET', 0))
    return Orders.objects.all()[offset: offset + abs(limit)]
```

Comment: `len(Orders.objects.all())` выглядит как лишний запрос в базу, в подобных случаях я бы пожертвовал упрощением ради оптимизации (ну и все описанные мной в комментариях проблемы здесь тоже присутствуют)

Comment: @andreymal, согласен. Добавил вариант для отсутствующего лимита

Comment: спасибо! станет попроще)

Comment: @andreymal, мне почему-то кажется, что закладываться на отрицательное значение `limit` излишне. Хотя, с другой стороны, почти ничего не стоит ))) Ну и если уж закладываться то через abs ИМХО. А искусственно ограничивать limit... Ну это по согласованию.

Comment: все-таки в вашем варианте если не передадут offset и limit, то Orders.objects.all()[offset: offset + abs(limit)] вернет [], а должен все объекты без фильтров, я так понимаю для решения проблемы нужно в качестве значения по умолчанию указывать количество значений в бд (либо какое-то условное значение), а не 0.

Comment: @Анонимныйволшебник, внимательно причтите закомментированный код